# Laravel touches with namespaces

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces

I have a model that exists in the namespace:

```
namespace Enquiry\Parts;
```

I'm trying to "touch" a different model:

```
protected $touches = array('Enquiry/Enquiry');
```

But this fails with:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Enquiry/Enquiry()
```

Alternatives also fail:

```
protected $touches = array('/Enquiry');
protected $touches = array('Enquiry');
```

How do I fix this?

---

As per Jeroen's answer, I created a relationship and adjusted $touches accordingly:

```
...
protected $touches = array('enquiry');
...
public function enquiry(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Enquiry\Enquiry', 'enquiryId');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a `belongsTo` relationship defined from the current model to the model that you want to touch. Then, put the name of the relationship (the method name) in the `$touches` array, not the model (class) name.

For example:

```
protected $touches = array('enquiry');

public function enquiry()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Enquiry/Enquiry');
}
```